# USB-C cables suddenly stop working

Tags: usb

I'm trying to diagnose a strange change in my setup. For the past 3 years I've had the same setup when working from home. I have a MacBook Pro (Intel, then M1 and now M2) connected to an Asus MX38VC 38" wide monitor via a USB-C -> USB-C cable. Then from the monitor's built in USB 3.1 hub I've got a USB-A -> USB-C Logitech Brio web cam and USB-A -> USB 3.0 Hub where I've got speakers and keyboard plugged into.

Until today it all worked just fine. Then this morning when I powered up the Logitech camera would not come online.

I rebooted the Mac, powered off everything but no change. Mac would not see the camera.

I unplugged the camera and plugged it directly in the MBP and it was instantly there. So the cable and camera are just fine.

Plugged it back into the monitor, and nothing. Power the monitor off and on again, checked its USB setup, but still nothing.

Plugged the camera into the downstream USB 3.0 hub plugged into the back of the monitor. Still nothing.

So I plugged the camera back into the monitor and switched cables and suddenly it came online. Switched back to the old cable, nothing via the monitor, fine direct to the MBP.

Changed to the original Logitech cable suppled with the camera. Also no good in the monitor and fine direct.

Found another spare cable in the drawer tried that. Worked. Fine in the monitor and fine direct.

So now I have two USB-A -> USB-C cables that won't work plugged into the monitor, but work fine with the camera plugged into the MBP. And two other USB-A -> USB-C cables that work fine is both situations.

Colour me confused.

As far as I can tell nothings changed in my setup from yesterday. And I don't see why two cables won't work whilst the other two will when all 4 appear to be the same. Especially when one of the non-working cables is the one supplied with the camera.

Everything else is working fine, so the only thing I can think of is that the two non-working cables must be some lower spec or something. There's certainly nothing written on them to indicate anything in terms of performance.

Anyone got any ideas? Could it be something else that's changed?

Comment: Cables go bad depending on how they are treated.  If they have sharp bends/kinks in them or have been inserted/removed from a port over and over things will break.  You may also have some corrosion on the contacts that will prevent a reliable signal from getting through.  Try reseating the cables to see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 0):

So I've spent two days messing about and learned a lot of things. One is that all of the USB-C cables I have seem to allow different versions of connectivity yet, despite the interwebs saying to look for labels of compatibility, none of them have anything printed on them. So I've had to guess based on what was happening as to what level of USB they supported.

Another thing I've discovered is that the Logitech Brio only appears to work well in a USB 2.0 Hub, or directly in the Mac's USB/Thunderbolt 4 socket. Why? anyone's guess.

I also tried connecting the Asus monitor via HDMI instead of relying on USB-C. To my surprise I was actually able to get higher refresh rates doing it that way, however if I then connected the MBP using the monitor's USB-C 3.1 cable, the Mac would then see two monitors attached. One through HDMI and one through USB-C. Obviously that was a no-go so now preferring the higher refresh rates available through HMDI I stepped down the USB-C cable to one that didn't allow the Mac to see the monitor as a display.

Using that setup I was then able to find a USB-C cable I could run from the monitor's builtin hub (USB-A) to the Logitech camera which would work reliably over restarts and power offs.

Interesting enough, with the Asus MX38VC monitor, it boasts 2 USB-A 3.0 Super speed sockets on the back, yet the Mac would only see it as a USB 2.0 hub regardless of what cable I used.

Comment: There’s another trick. USB-3 hubs are usb-2 hubs at the same time. If you plug in only USB-2 devices you will see a usb-2 hub and possibly no usb-3. If you plug in only usb-3 devices you see a USB-3 hub and possibly no usb-2. Plug in one of each and you see two hubs.

Answer (score 0):

You want a Thunderbolt cable, which looks exactly like a usb 3 cable except for something printed on it. I had the problem with a monitor that worked just fine with a usb-3 cable and stopped working overnight.

This can be confusing. “USB-C” just means the cable has two USB-C connectors. But it can be Thunderbolt, USB-3, sometimes only USB-2, it can carry 60, 100 or 240 Watt of power (and for reasons I don’t understand 60 and 240 Watt must be marked and 100 Watt doesn’t).